# Grant users access to Azure OpenAI-Studio and/or GPT-3 Playground

Tags: azure, permissions, openai-api, azure-openai

I would be interested to know if you can use one of the BuiltInRoles to give users access to the Azure OpenAI-Studio and/or GPT-3 Playground only? I don't want to give users admin rights in my subscription or resource group just so they can work with GPT Playground.

I have looked for the existing roles and have not found a suitable one. I would expect there to be a role that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 built-in roles dedicated to Azure OpenAI:

- Cognitive Services OpenAI Contributor
- Cognitive Services OpenAI User

Azure OpenAI Studio is a web portal provided by Microsoft: anyone with an Azure AD account can access it, but will face a message asking to select an existing Azure OpenAI resource ou register to the service if none found.

=> You can simply add your target user as `Cognitive Services OpenAI User` on the Azure OpenAI resource you have and they will be able to use the Studio.

Note that there is no "per deployment" restriction; it's all or nothing (at least at the moment).

[image]

Details on the permissions for the "User" role:
[image]